# Page template anomaly

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template

I have created a page with some text in it using this page-about.php as a template; page-about.php contains the basic:

```
<?php /* Template Name: About us */
get_header(); ?>
        <div id="primary">
            <div id="content" role="main">      

                <?php 
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  the_content(); 
                endwhile; 
                ?>

            </div><!-- #content -->
        </div><!-- #primary --> 

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

What I don't really understand, if I create another page, let's say Coaching, assign page-coaching.php to it as a template, page-coaching.php having the same content as the one above but with /* Template Name: Coaching */, of course, when I view the page is showing me the content of the Homepage? And also Coaching disappeared from the menu?!

This is driving me crazy, any suggestions please?

I have created custom post types for both, exact copies, just changed about to coaching from one part to another, like this:

```
// Custom post type => ABOUT US
add_action( 'init', 'create_about' );
function create_about() {
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x('About us', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('About us', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'About us'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New About us'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit About us'),
    'new_item' => __('New About us'),
    'view_item' => __('View About us'),
    'search_items' => __('Search About us'),
    'not_found' =>  __('No About us found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No About us found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
  );

  $supports = array('title', 'editor', 'revisions', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes');

  register_post_type( 'about',
    array(
      'labels' => $labels,
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'hierarchical' => true,
      'query_var' => true,
      'supports' => $supports
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: why do you have a post type for about us? That doesn't make sense...

Comment: As it will have several pages underneath which are going to be listed as a menu on the left side while in the About section, and I have chosen to use post types so I will have them nicely separated on the left side rather than having to simply create pages and assign then to a category.

Comment: What about just using pages and subpages? Your code is ALL whacked up for what you're trying to do...so I'm trying to figure out what the best advice to give you is before I give it.

Comment: Cristian that way of doing things is confusing and does not scale beyond a handful of pages. It also removes any sense of heirarchy and adds new problems for you to fix. If you need a sidemenu, just use a menu widget and sub pages

Comment: It appears that WordPress is doing *exactly what you're telling it to do*. Do you want to use *static Pages*, or do you want to use *custom posts*? You really can't mix-and-match the two.

Comment: Thank you for advices guys. OK, I understand, but I will have 4 pages, every single page will have 3-8 subpages and 2 of these subpages will have posts. Am I still not right thinking of making custom post types for the major sections I will have as is it going to be a lot easier adding pages to the right section?

Comment: What do you mean @Chip Bennett? I think I've seen so many people/posts around here having a static page for a custom post type, am I wrong? Why would this not work? Is working for me for the other page, I am getting really confused now.

Comment: A *static Page* **is** a post-type (the `page` post-type). A custom post type is a *separate* post-type. I don't think you can make a post of a custom post type to be a child of a post of a different post-type, e.g. a `page` post-type. A post of a custom post type would need to be a child of a post of the *same* post-type.

Comment: Oh, OK, you are right, but I am not trying to achieve that at all. The page created using Pages section is just a landing page for a particular Custom Post Type where I was thinking to get links to the taxonomy created under that specific custom post type. Am I making any sense? Once the login lands on the landing page, he is taken to "singles" and browse between them. Or he is taken to a taxonomy page where I have posts or pages inside.. I think I am going to drop the idea as you guys seem to be so against it, I am a bit frustrated as I've seen people doing it and spent a day already on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created a specific page template for a page called 'about' but your page is called 'About Us'. Try creating a page named 'About' or renaming your file to page-about-us.php.

Also use the cleaner formatting involving new lines:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Example Page
*/
get_header();
?>
```

You're also not checking if there is a post and executing the loop regardless

```
if( have_posts()){
    // put the while loop here
}
```

I have no idea why you have involved custom post types for this. You're working with a page template, and you assign page templates to pages. Those custom post type definitions may even be interfering with the working of your pages if they have the same post type name as your pages slug.

Comment: Renaming the page doesn't change a thing, as it can have any name as long as the chosen template is pointing to that page, am I wrong? I've done it anyway and this didn't change a thing. I have also reformatted the Template Name at the top without any changes.

Comment: Remove the custom post type code. Also page templates only work for pages. You cannot use a page template on a custom post type, you will need to use a different kind of template for that

Comment: Even if you refuse to remove the insanity that is the custom post type idea, at the very least, prefix the post types name with a common prefix

Comment: Hang on a second, the pages are created from Pages, not from the Custom post type menu. Like anyone would create a normal page, assign a template for it. And removing entirely the custom post types functions/code doesn't help either.

Comment: Note, if you have a custom page template named `page-about.php`, and a static Page named "About", then WordPress will *automagically* use that `page-about.php` template file to render the "About" page. Refer to the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Page_display).

Comment: Yes, you are right and I know this. But I think Tom misunderstood as my problem comes when I create exact copies or my about page for another page (and change everything accordingly), and that doesn't show nothing but the content of index.php.

Comment: If WordPress cannot find templates, as a last resort it uses index.php

Comment: That it is not picking up page.php indicates something is wrong with your setup or things are missing